# add_action in a custom plugin

Tags: plugins, actions, cookies, init

I did a plugin to create a  when the cookie is FALSE. Actually, the  was working, but when I was about to create the cookie, it said that my header was already sent.

Then, I had the code `add_action('init', 'newsletterSuscriber');` but it still returned an error like this one.

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'newsletterSuscriber' not found or invalid function name in /PATH/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 503

**Plugin code**

```
    class Okidoo_Newsletter_Suscriber {

    /**
    * Initializes the plugin.
    *
    * To keep the initialization fast, only add filter and action in the constructor.
    */

    public function __construct() {

        add_shortcode( 'custom-suscribe-form' , array( $this, 'render_suscribe_form') );

        add_action( 'init', 'newsletterSuscriber' );
    }



    /**
    * A shortcode for rendering the login form.
    *
    * @param    array   $attributes     Shortcode attributes.
    * @param    array   $content        The text content for shortcode. Not used.
    * 
    * @return   string                  The shortcode output
    */

    public function render_suscribe_form( $attributes, $content = null ) {

        // Parse shortcode attributes
        $default_attributes = array( 'show_title' => false );
        $attributes = shortcode_atts( $default_attributes, $attributes );
        $show_title = $attributes['show_title'];

        // Pass the redirect parameter to the WordPress login functionnality : by default,
        // don't specify a redirect, but if a valid redirect URL has been passed as 
        // request parameter, use it.
        $attributes['redirect'] = '';

        // Render the login form using an external template.
        return $this->get_template_html( 'subscription_form', $attributes );
    }


    /**
    * Render the contents of the given template to a string and returns it.
    * @param    string  $template_name  The name of the template to render (without .php)
    * @param    array   $attributes     The PHP variables for the template
    *
    * @return   string                  The contents of the template.
    */
    private function get_template_html( $template_name, $attributes = null ) {
        if ( ! $attributes ) {
            $attributes = array();
        }

        ob_start();

        do_action( 'personalize_div_before_' . $template_name );

        require( 'templates/' . $template_name . '.php' );

        do_action( 'personalize_div_before_' . $template_name );

        $html = ob_get_contents();

        ob_end_clean();

        return $html;
    }

    public function newsletterSuscriber() {
        if ( ! isset($_COOKIE['newsletter_suscriber'])) {

            $path = parse_url(get_option('siteurl'), PHP_URL_PATH);
            $host = parse_url(get_option('siteurl'), PHP_URL_HOST);
            $expiration = time() + 3600;

            setcookie('newsletter_suscriber', 'newsletter_suscriber', $expiration, $path, $host);
        }
    }

}

// Initialize the plugin
$initialisation = new Okidoo_Newsletter_Suscriber();
```

Afer this, I have try to place the add_action on mey functions.php file in the template and also in the plugin file directly.

Any one can tell me if it is possible to :

1. Execute a plugin with the init action;
2. What I am doing wrong if point #1 is true?

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It errors because class method is not a function. It's not uniquely identified by its name alone. You need to provide instance of the object (or name of the class for static methods).

In your context it would be:

```
add_action( 'init', [ $this, 'newsletterSuscriber' ] );
```

Comment: That thing did the job I wanted to do. I will try to read more about your explination on the Codex. Meanwhile, can you tell me if it is the good way to do so?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking precisely. :) Nothing jumps out at me as horribly wrong with your code, but I hadn't looked closely beyond your issue.